# Как работать с .find_every_bitmap (autopy, Python)?

Tags: python

При поиске пропускает изображения, расположенные в той же строке, т.к. если находит изображение, сразу переносит поиск на следующую строку.

Это заметно при поиске на четких изображениях, например, захват экрана Компаса, ищем изображение цифры пять. Найдет, но меньшее количество.

При задании ошибки поиска ноль, программа работает хорошо.

По реальным объектам, например при поиске зданий по фотографии из космоса?
MatLab при обработке фотографии  по сумме модулей разности пикселей, дает хорошие результаты.

Попутный вопрос, о невозможности сохранить объект на диск после .get_portion((x,y),(Н,V))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для уверенного поиска можно применять одиночный поиск с последующим изменением области поиска, .get_portion((x,y),(Н,V)).

После нахождения первого изображения, задаем область поиска правее от найденного изображения, а затем переносим область поиска в начало следующей строки.